# How to revert Kanban dashboard in Tuleap?

Tags: agile, kanban, tuleap

I am using Tuleap v.10.3.99.55, in that I have created one project which is using Agile dashboard for the sprint. It was working fine. For enable cardwall, I have active kanban dashboard on the same project and that time I don't know that cardwall display only kanban task in the wall. So I have deactivated kanban dashboard because my all task are available in sprint dashboard. But after deactivate my sprint dashboard not working properly. Still, it's trying to display kanban task in the sprint and that is not available in the project.

Can you please help to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

your_kanban > "edit this kanban" > Delete the kanban

[image]

[image]